# Why don't any Arizona craft breweries export their beer?

Tags: breweries

Why don't any Arizona craft breweries export beers out of state?  Is it a legal restriction, a private agreement, or just a market force?

Comment: This is likely an issue with state legislation and how they are typically licensed. There should probably be a meta discussion about how much legal stuff we want to be on topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States, interstate beer export is an extraordinarily complicated matter.  Unlike other areas of commerce, states are allowed to directly regulate import of alcoholic beverages to their state because of the 21st Amendment specifically reserved that right in the repealing of prohibition.  States, through the licensing process, can also control export, but this is rare since usually states like to export stuff to other states (and thus bring money into their state).

This means that beer, wine, and spirits are extraordinarily complex to sell in the interstate market.  Small craft breweries are going to have a huge amount of legal compliance in every case and so you have an issue that it is essentially impossible to be both small and interstate in this market.